# Access request in Mongoose virtual property

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Consider this sample

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    content: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}, {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});
ArticleSchema.virtual('is_owner').get(function () {
    //how to access app request here?
    //i would like to get req.user variable here
    return false;
});
mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

As written in comment, i want to access route request inside virtual property, but don't know is that even legal?

First idea was to require express inside virtual

```
ArticleSchema.virtual('is_owner').get(function () {
        var express = require('express');
        var app = express();
        //then what?
    });
```

But app doesn't have request

Answer (score -1):

Let's say this is your route:

```
app.post('/articles', function newArticle(req, res, next) {

  var article = new Article(req.body);
  article.set('is_owner', req);
  article.save(function onSaved(err, savedArticle) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.json(savedArticle);
  });

});
```

and this is your virtual:

```
ArticleSchema.virtual('is_owner').set(function (req) {
  // => do what ever you want here.
});
```

Comment: But how can i access it? Although virtual-prop is saved, it doesn't return this `is_owner` field. Setting prop is not much usefull in my case, i would like to `get` it. 

[The getters are useful for formatting or combining fields, while setters are useful for de-composing a single value into multiple values for storage.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Comment: [Here's my model.js and ctrl.js](http://pastebin.com/7cCrkXDn) what im doing wrong? can't access virtual_prop neither object field not populated